# First three images in post excerpt

Tags: gallery, excerpt

I have certain posts that are nothing but [gallery] with quite a few images in them. Is there a way to define  an auto generated excerpt to only display the first three images for these posts on the index, so that users would have to click through to see the rest? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using the `do_shortcode` function.

### Check if an instance of `[gallery]` exists in your post content.

Here's a simple function to drop in functions.php that checks the current post's content for the gallery shortcode:

```
function gallery_shortcode_exists(){

    global $post;

    # Check the content for an instance of [gallery] with or without arguments
    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
    if(
        preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches )
        && array_key_exists( 2, $matches )
        && in_array( 'gallery', $matches[2] )
    )
        return true;

    # Sourced from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex
}
```

### Use `do_shortcode()` to render your gallery.

You can use the following within the loop in your template files:

```
# Determine if the post_content column contains the string [gallery]
if( gallery_shortcode_exists() ){

    # Get the first three attachments using the posts_per_page parameter
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID()
    );
    $attachments = get_children( $args );

    # If any attachments are returned, proceed
    if( $attachments ){

        # Spin cycle to collate attachment IDs
        foreach( $attachments as $attachment )
            $includes[] = $attachment->ID;

        # Format our IDs in a comma-delimited string
        $includes = implode(',', $includes);

        # Inject your include argument
        $shortcode = str_replace('[gallery', "[gallery include='$includes' ", get_the_content());

        # Render the Gallery using the standard editorial input syntax
        echo do_shortcode($shortcode);

        # Add a View More link
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . __('View more', 'domain') . '</a>';
    }
    else
        _e('Foo Bar - No attachments found and no excerpt to display', 'domain');
}
else
    # Whatever fallback you desire
    the_excerpt();
```

Comment: Some notes: I'd check `gallery_shortcode_exists() OR 'gallery' === get_post_type()`. Second: Why the heck are _you_ using a query string? :) Third: No more filter? and fourth: `count`ing in the condition check is slower than doing it right before. +1 anyway

Comment: Hm, after thinking about it again, maybe you should check for theme support `gallery` before checking for the post type.

Comment: Works great, but some of the images that were excluded in the gallery shortcode are showing up in the three on index page `[gallery exclude="1,2,3" link="file"]` file ids 1,2 and 3 would show up in the excerpt. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @kaiser Nothing was stated in the question about a gallery post type. This is only the native WP `[gallery]` shortcode. There was also no mention of a gallery post format, maybe I'm missing your point. Also, not sure what filter you're referring to...

Comment: @sosukeinu Check out my latest edit, it should keep your shortcodes intact.

Comment: @BrianFegter No, it wasn't mentioned. I just thought that it might be faster if you already know A) that it's supported and B) the post type term is attached, than doing the regex.

Comment: @kaiser I see now. That is the intuitive way to set this up on his end. Though, it's not applicable because I think he's using posts and shortcodes out-of-the-box without new cpt or post format. I do like your approach. :)

Comment: I like @kaiser approach also, but unfortunately, I'm already invested in using posts and shortcodes. I tried your edits. here is my actual loop : http://pastebin.com/yyQWnh2A
and unfortunately, I'm still getting excluded images in the exerpt. This is specifically happing with [gallery] that only has 2 images, and it's dropping the featured image into the excerpt, even though I have it excluded in the gallery shortcode. Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: @kaiser you're absolutely right, fixed that. thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the loop is still not respecting my excludes in my shortcode, and so is posting my featured images in the excerpt as well. I'm going to keep trying things, but up until now, have not met with success. any suggestions will be eagerly implemented. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked this. Change to this    `echo do_shortcode($shortcode);`

Comment: this works to get rid of the featured image, but does nothing to keep the other excluded images from showing up in the excerpt.
    $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
  'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
       );
  $attachments = get_children( $args );

Comment: Can you just echo $shortcode and see what that gives you?